# JPA Query Method using IN operator breaks in Oracle

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jpa, spring-data-jpa

We recently switched the datasource of a Spring-Boot REST API from Postgres to Oracle. All the tables and table names are the same across the 2 databases.

After the switch we started getting the following error on any queries using the 'IN' operator with JPA Query methods.

> ORA-01797: this operator must be followed by ANY or ALL

We get this error on all queries like the following:

```
List<String> listOfStringValues;
List<MyClass> myClass = myClassRepository.findByColumnNameIn(listOfStringValues);
```

These queries/endpoints all worked fine in Postgres, but now in Oracle we get the error. Does anyone know what's causing the error and how to fix it?

**Update**

I was able to resolve the issue by using the following query syntax in the repository interface:

```
@Query("select * from TableName t where t.ColumnName in (:listOfStringValues)")
List<MyClass> findByColumnNameIn(
    @Param("listOfStringValues") 
    Collection<String> listOfStringValues);
```

Comment: Can you check and post the SQL query being executed for one of these cases? Specifically, can you check whether the SQL query is `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE columnName = (...)` instead of `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE columnName IN (...)`?

Comment: @manish Yes, that is exactly what the error message is suggesting is happening. How would we check the SQL that is executed? Where does the JPA method get translated to plain SQL?

Comment: This varies by the JPA provider. For example, Hibernate has a property called `show_sql` that can be set to `true` to print the SQL queries to logs. Consult the Spring Boot documentation, if using that or `LocalContainerEntityManagerBean` documentation if using Spring Data JPA directly.